# Passing Todays Date to an EditText Variable on Button Click in a Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, android, datetime, android-edittext

I am trying to pass todays date (which is being capture when the USE DATE button is click) to a EditText variable to be displayed as input.  I have the following code:

```
btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Create New Bowler
                Series newSeries = new Series();

                // Set Variables To Match User Entry On The Form
                newSeries.setTitle(editTitle.getText().toString());

                // Apply Date As Series Name
                SimpleDateFormat TodaysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
                EditText.setText(R.id.editTitleSeries+TodaysDate.toString());

                // Reference To BowlerActivity
                SeriesActivity callingActivity = (SeriesActivity) getActivity();

                // Pass Bowler Back To BowlersActivity
                callingActivity.createNewSeries(newSeries);

                // Quit the dialog
                dismiss();
            }
        });
```

However I am getting the following error on the .setText; error: non-static method setText(CharSequence) cannot be referenced from a static context.  I understand the error, but I am have not been able to resolve why I am getting this.  Also I don't believe that the way I am attempting to get the date is correct.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that the java naming convention dictates that classes are capitalized while methods and variables are not! That means that your code will probably confuse a lot of java programmers. Variables like "TodaysDate"  should not be capitalized. Same with "EditText.setText()". Because "EditText"  is also the class name for the `EditText` view!

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the date formatted do this:

```
private String getDateNow() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Now you can set the date value like this:

```
String dateNow = getDateNow();
myEditText.setText(dateNow);
```

BTW:: I have absolutely no idee what you want to acheive with this:

?? `EditText.setText(R.id.editTitleSeries+TodaysDate.toString());` ??

If you are using dates of different formats often it is worth the effort to create a utility class to maintain all the methods you need.

**EDIT**

BTW:
In your code the "TodaysDate"  is a `SimpleDateFormat` object not a `Date` object.

Comment: Basically when I create a new item for a list I want to have the option to type in a name for the item or to use today's date.  I was attempting to assign the formatted text to edit text field called edittextseries.  I was unable access it without the R.id.

Comment: If your are using the code in an `Activity` then make an class variable holding the `EditText` view.  Then Initialize the class variable in the `onCreate` method. Now you can use the variable anywhere within the `Activity` to set the text (as long as you are on the main UI thread).

Comment: @RobertVogl :: ?? " I was unable access it without the R.id." ?? Note that "R.id.editTitleSeries"  is actually just an `int` value so `String s = R.id.editTitleSeries + myDateString;`  will give you something like "378946312.30.2010"  if myDateString = "12.30.2010"

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice.  I was able to accomplish this by slightly modifying the code you supplied above.  I will keep in mind the advice about the variable names when creating them.